# How DragMove works? (Which properties it changes?)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a simple window in WPF (like Overwolf), in Overwolf there is a circle in the top-left of the screen and when you drag it, its moving back to the corner with simple Animation.
So I tried to make the same effect using DoubleAnimation on the LeftProperty but it only works once (**The first time you drag its working**, **the second its just stay where you dragged it**).

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Overwoof.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Name="Main"
    Width="200" 
    Height="200" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle='None' 
    IsHitTestVisible="True"
    Topmost="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="onDragLeave"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual">
<Grid IsHitTestVisible="True" Name="mainGrid" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
    <Ellipse MouseLeftButtonDown="DragStart" Name="logo" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.5" Margin="12,24,66,37" IsManipulationEnabled="True" />
</Grid>
```

My C# code:

```
private void DragStart(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.DragMove();
    }

    private void onDragLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = Main.Left;
        da.To = -20;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2));
        da.Completed += new EventHandler(AnimationCompleted);
        Main.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, da);
    }
```

Thx, BBLN.

Answer (score 1):

change `da.To = -20;`  to`da.To -= 20;`

Comment: That wasn't the problem, I got it working now.
Just add "Main.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, null);" before DragMove. (fail :D)